# How to solve an ODE and a nonlinear PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to relearn a bajillion concepts and learn the symmetry method of solving differential equations.

I am working through an example so that I can check my answers.
However, the step by step method is not there, so I am stuck.

I have found system of determining equations and now need to solve each one.

Please can someone show me or direct me to a textbook that will explain how to solve the following:

$ \xi_{yy} + \frac{1}{y} \xi_{y} = 0 $

and

$ \eta_{yy} - 2\xi_{xy} - \frac{1}{y} \eta_{y} + \frac{1}{y^2} \eta = 0 $

for $\eta(x,y)$ and $\xi(x,y)$

Many thanks,

Sincerely,

Sarah

Comment: The first one is just an ode.

Comment: @TonyS.F. sorry my error, I will edit the the heading and question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the equation for $\xi$. We have,

$$\xi_{yy} +\frac{1}{y}\xi_y = 0\\
\implies y\xi_{yy} + \xi_y=0$$

which is a Cauchy-Euler equation with solution $\xi(x,y) = c_1(x)\log(y) + c_2(x)$.

From here we calculate $\xi_{xy} = \frac{c_1'(x)}{y}$ and substitute into the equation for $\eta$,

$$\eta_{yy} - 2\frac{c_1'(x)}{y} -\frac{1}{y}\eta_y + \frac{1}{y^2}\eta=0$$

This is again an ode in the variable $y$ (in fact, another Cauchy-Euler equation).

Comment: will I need to use variation of parameters to solve for $\eta$ ? does the $\xi_{xy}$ term make this nonhomogenous?

Comment: Yes it's inhomogeneous so you will have to use something like variation of parameters.

Comment: when i solve it i get the following:  $$ C(x)y +D(x)y\ln\left|y\right| - A'(x)y\left(\ln\left|y\right|\right)^2 + A'(x)y^3\ln\left|y\right| $$ the last term is not supposed to be there.  All the other terms are correct.  Have I done something wrong, or do I omit the last term because the power of $y$ is greater than 2?

Comment: We have $y^2 \eta_{yy} - y\eta_y + \eta = 2c_1'(x)y$ which has solution $\eta = c_1'(x)y\log^2(y)+k_1(x)y + k_2(x)y\log(y)$. See here, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E2+w%27%27+-+y+w%27+%2B+w+%3D+2cy

Comment: I am trying to get the solution.  I am obviously slipping up somewhere.  The link only offers step by step solutions for paid subscribers.  Im trying variation of parameters by finding the Wronskian.  will post my steps shortly.

Comment: @sarahjamal Yes, please post your work and I will see what's going on.

Comment: Found my error. I had dropped a coefficient  thanks so much

Comment: No problem. Can I ask what you were looking at that led to this system of determining equations? I am also someone interested in symmetry methods of pdes.

Comment: It was an example from P.Hydon's textbook.  $y'' = \frac{(y')^2}{y} - y^2 $

Comment: how do i solve $\eta_{xx} - \frac{1}{y^2}\eta_x = 0$ the coefficients in y and derivatives with respect to x are throwing me off :(

Comment: Integrate once with respect to $x$ and then you have a separable equation. We have $\eta_x -\frac{1}{y^2}\eta = f(y)$ which can be rearranged to $\frac{d\eta}{f(y) + \frac{1}{y^2}\eta} = dx$. Integrate both sides now.